# Django отдельный email для отправки сообщений об ошибках

Tags: python, django, email

Здравствуйте. Требуется сделать отдельный почтовый ящик для отправки сообщений об ошибках. В принципе в документации [такой случай описан](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports) как переменная SERVER_EMAIL, но дело в том, что при отправке сообщения происходит следующая ошибка:

`SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password!')`

Насколько я могу судить по коду django это всё потому, что используется одно соединение, а почты используются как логины - EMAIL_HOST_USER используется для отправки почты по умолчанию, а SERVER_EMAIL - для сообщений модераторам и администраторам. Соответственно поэтому и не требуется пароль от SERVER_EMAIL (и именно поэтому установка одинакового пароля на эти две почты не помогает).

Сейчас использую примерно следующие настройки, но это не работает:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = u'info@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = u'EXAMPLECOM <info@example.com>'

SERVER_EMAIL = u'server@example.com'
```

Как решить эту проблему? Как рассылать почту с разных ящиков пользователям (напр. info@example.com) и администраторам (напр. server@example.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решили проблему переопределением [LOGGERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/).

Получилось примерно следующее:

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            # Этот используется по умолчанию
            # 'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'class': 'jsp.fjlogging.FJErrorAdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': False,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}


# jsp.fjlogging
from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler
from django.core.mail import get_connection
from django.conf import settings


class FJErrorAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
    def connection(self):
        return get_connection(
            backend=self.email_backend,
            host=getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_EMAIL_HOST', None),
            port=getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_EMAIL_PORT', None),
            username=getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_EMAIL_USER', None),
            password=getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_EMAIL_PASS', None),
            use_tls=getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_EMAIL_USE_TLS', None),
            fail_silently=True
        )
```

В settings.py надо указать ваши параметры соединения с почтовым серваком - все параметры объявлены в классе. Например:

```
ADMIN_EMAIL_USER = u'error@example.com'
ADMIN_EMAIL_PASS = 'MySuperPass'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать пакет [Django Email Multibackend](https://github.com/tbarbugli/django_email_multibackend)